# How do I show a hidden subtitle in a UITableView when selected?

Tags: uitableview, swift, subtitle, detailtextlabel

Is there a way to hide the subtitles of all the cells until you select a cell - then it only shows you that cell's subtitle? I tried the following code - which successfully hides all the subtitles but fails to show one when I select a cell:

```
if cell.selected {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.hidden = false
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.hidden = true
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit 2 - I ended up doing this in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    for cell in tableView.visibleCells() {
        cell.detailTextLabel??.hidden = true
    }
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.hidden = false

}
```

**Thanks very much, Christian!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and access the touched cell. Then you can show the detailTextLabel.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)  as UITableViewCell

    cell.detailTextLabel?.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: This sure looks like what I need to do but I can't get it to work. Either they are all there if I don't set them to hidden in the storyboard or they are all hidden and don't show when I select a row - even with this override. I'll add more of my code above - maybe it's something to do with something else in there? thanks very much, Christian

Comment: where do you hide the labels? I think the problem is that you hide it in a function which gets called everytime something happens in The tableview. Maybe cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: in the storyboard, where can I put it?

Comment: Where do you have your cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = false  at the moment in which method?

Comment: I moved it to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath like you suggested, I had that if then else I posted above in my cellForRowAtIndexPath before I saw your answer. I'll post an edit to the OP with both my full cellForRowAtIndexPath and my new didSelectRowAtIndexPath that you gave me...

Comment: Do you know why this is creating a bug for me - when you select a cell - it correctly unhides the detailTextLabel for that cell but it also unhides it for next cell under the last one you can't see (you'll see if if you scroll down).  As you scroll down the list you can see a cell about every 12 cells that has it's detailTextLabel revealed - tapping on a different correctly hides all the ones you can see but when you scroll you'll see more from that point on...strange